# Не работает данная функция, выдает ошибку "list index out of range", хотя перед return я проверяю условие, как грамотно изменить функцию?

Tags: python

```
def dehydrate_Author2(self, book):
        authors_list = book.author.all()
        if authors_list.count()>1:
            return str(authors_list[1].first_name)+str(authors_list[1].second_name)
        return ""
```

Comment: Приведите пример класса book

Answer (score 1):

```py
def dehydrate_Author2(self, book):
        authors_list = book.author.all()
        if len(authors_list)>1:
            return str(authors_list[1].first_name)+str(authors_list[1].second_name)
        return ""
```

Comment: не работает так)

Comment: @dima Покажите пример `authors_list`

Comment: там обьекты Author

Comment: @dima Можете показать пример? Там просто объекты или список объектов, так как название переменной намекает на это.